# Please help me with JUnit test cases for the code below

Tags: java

I want to know the JUnit test cases for the following program.please help. I have not included the main method here. Want to know the JUnit test cases for the url() method in the code. This code is to read HTML from a website and save it in a file in local machine

```
    package Java3;

        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.io.PrintStream;
        import java.net.MalformedURLException;
        import java.net.URL;
        import java.util.logging.Level;
        import java.util.logging.Logger;


        public class Urltohtml 
        {
            private String str;
            public void url() throws IOException
            {
                try 
                {
                    FileOutputStream f=new FileOutputStream("D:/File1.txt");
                    PrintStream p=new PrintStream(f);

                    URL u=new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(u.openStream()));
                    //str=br.readLine();
                    while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                        System.out.println(str+"\n");
                        p.println(str);
                    }
                } 
                catch (MalformedURLException ex) 
                {
                    Logger.getLogger(Urltohtml.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Mocks, mocks everywhere!  But on a serious note, we can't just write the test code for you.  Think about this:  What parts of this method can you pull out to test in isolation?  What can you pass into the method itself to ease the effort of testing it?  (Hint:  Please don't hard-code the file path.)

Answer (score 2):

I would rename that class to `UrlToHtml` and write a single JUnit test class `UrlToHtmlTest`.

Part of the reason why you're having problems testing this is that the class is poorly designed and implemented:

1. You should pass in the URL you want to scrape, not hard code it.
2. You should return the content as a String or List, not print it to a file.
3. You might want to throw that exception rather than catch it.  Your logging isn't exactly "handling" the exceptional situation.  Let it bubble out and have clients log if they wish.
4. You don't need that private data member; return the contents.  That lets you make this method static.

Good names matter.  I don't like what you have for the class or the method.

Why are you writing this when you could use a library to do it?

Here's what the test class might look like:

```
public class UrlToHtmlTest {
    @Test
    public void testUrlToHtml() {
       try { 
           String testUrl = "http://www.google.com" ;
           String expected = "";
           String actual = UrlToHtml.url(testUrl);
           Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           Assert.fail();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for explaining. Am new to this. Btw this is th complete question that i need to solve::

Comment: You will have to write a program in Java on Eclipse IDE  to do following things

1) To read HTML from any website say "http://www.google.com" ( You can use any API of inbuilt APIs in Java like URLConnection )
2) Print on console the HTML from the url above and save it to a file ( web-content.txt) in local machine .
3) JUnit test cases for the above programme.

*To qualify the test you have to do all the 3 parts of the program.

Comment: @user3233164 did you get your answer means is it enough as test case for this program..as i also had the same interview test..